# I have a javascript scope error, I don't know how to fix this

Tags: javascript, function, class, prototype

the browser is telling me in 'Task.prototype.start' 'this.clear' is undefined...
Here is the class (function) and it's prototypes:

```
function Task(_func, _ms, _repeats, _args)
{
    if (typeof _func != 'function') throw '_func is not `function`';
    if (typeof _ms != 'number') throw '_ms is not `number`';
    if (typeof _repeats != 'number') _repeats = 0; // default: no repeats, run once. optional
    // _args is optional
    this.func = _func;
    this.ms = _ms;
    this.repeats = _repeats;
    this.args = _args;
    this.tID = 0;
    this.runCounter = 0;
}

Task.prototype.isRunning = function()
{
    return (this.tID != 0);
};
Task.prototype.runsOnce = function(){
    return (this.repeats == 0);
};
Task.prototype.clear = function()
{
    if (this.isRunning())
    {
        if (this.runsOnce())
        {
            clearTimeout(this.tID);
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(this.tID);
        }
    }
    this.tID = 0;
    this.runCounter = 0;
};
Task.prototype.start = function()
{
    this.clear();
    var _this = this;
    var _exec = function()
    {
        if (_this.runsOnce())
        {
            _this.func(_this.args);
            _this.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            if (_this.runCounter > 0)
            {
                _this.runCounter--;
                _this.func(_this.args);
            }
            else if (_this.runCounter == -1)
            {
                _this.func(_this.args);
            }
            else
            {
                _this.clear();
            }
        }
    };
    if (this.runsOnce())
    {
        this.runCounter = 0;
        this.tID = setTimeout(_exec, this.ms);
    }
    else
    {
        this.runCounter = this.repeats;
        this.tID = setInterval(_exec, this.ms);
    }
}
```

EDIT: how I use it...

```
Task.tasks = {};
Task.exists = function(_ID)
{
    return (_ID in Task.tasks);
}
Task.create = function(_func, _ms, _repeats, _args, _ID)
{
    if (Task.exists(_ID)) return;
    Task.tasks[_ID] = new Task(_func, _ms, _repeats, _args);
}
Task.start = function(_ID)
{
    if (!Task.exists(_ID)) return;
    Task.tasks[_ID].start();
}
Task.clear = function(_ID)
{
    if (!Task.exists(_ID)) return;
    Task.tasks[_ID].clear();
}


//test task
__task = new Task(function(a){console.log( (new Date()).getTime()+': '+a ) }, 2000, 0, '[args]');
```

Comment: if you know any better class for making a task, please let me know!

Comment: Why in the world do you define both `Task.prototype.start` and `Task.start`?  That does not make sense.

Comment: second one is static method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. Make sure you're instatiating with `new` :

```
var task = new Task(...);
task.start();
```

Probably you're doing:

```
var task = Task(...);
```

that would not create a proper `this` value causing the error.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that error in the `.start()` method, then that is because the `this` value is not what it is supposed to be.  And, that problem probably occurs because of the way you call the `.start()` method.  Since you don't show us how you call the `.start()` method we can't help specifically on what is wrong there.  But, you need to make sure that it is called with the form `obj.start()` where `obj` is a `Task` object.

A common mistake in this regard is to pass `obj.start` as a callback and not realize that it won't be called as `obj.start()` by whomever calls the callback.

Please include how you are calling `.start()` for us to help more specifically.